# Map the states from the data in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have stored all the data in state variable.so How to map all the states of the particular country.
My data is-

[image]

Comment: please send it in string and let us copy, but not image

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like;

```
response.data.map(country => {
    return {
        ...country,
        states: country.states.map(state => {
            // return whatever you would like map `state` to
            return {
                ...state,
                newKey: 'newValue'
            };
        })
    };
})
```